# IE Automatin Clicking buttons VBA

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, automation

I can't able to access the submit button from my HTML code, I tried some codes but those things are not working. hope you folks will find the solution from the below info.

My Code:

```
Sub GetIE()

Dim shellWins As ShellWindows
Dim IE As InternetExplorer

Set shellWins = New ShellWindows
Set IE = shellWins.Item(0)

IE.document.all("linerepricedamount").Value = "Value"
IE.document.all("linestatus").Value = "value"

'In Next step i want to click a submit button
'I Tried everything but those codes are not working

Set IE = Nothing
Set shellWins = Nothing

End Sub
```

HTML CODE:

```
<TD> <Input id="button" Type="Button" Value= "SaveLine" Name= "Button"
onclick="JavaScript:return save_line_onclick("saveline.d")> </TD>`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fire the onclick event

```
Dim btnObject as Object

Set btnObject = IE.document.getElementbyID("button")
    btnObject.FireEvent("onclick")
```

Hope this solves your problem